# how to make a combobo blank then fill it with a color when disabled in Extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox

Ive got a simple request.. how can i make a combo box blank after i have disabled it? Is it possible to do it without adding a value Field and display field for the blank option?

Also how do i fill the combo box with a certain color once it is disabled and blank??

Here is what i have for the combo box set up....

```
  //PROTOCOL COMBO BOX!
var protocol_cbox = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
   // lazyRender: true ,
    mode: 'local',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
       id: 0,
       fields: [
           'myId',
           'displayText'
       ],
       data: [[1, 'Ethernet'], [2, 'Serial']]
   }),
   valueField: 'myId',
   displayField: 'displayText',
});
```

Again .. i want to achieve making this combo box blank without having an option for it in the data field of the store. is this possible?  Basically when the combo box is enable i just want the drop down to contain "Ethernet" and "serial".. and when disable just go blank   and then get filled with a color.

THANK YOU GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

Use [diabledCls](http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-disabledCls) to set the style, example css selector to change the color of combo's field

```
.my-combo-disabled .x-form-field {
    background: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

use [setValue](http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue) with an empty string while disabling to make it blank.
Sample fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1et

Comment: hmm where do i add this?? inside my combo box?

Comment: new mount thanks for your reply..I am using 3.4  disabledCls is not avaialble in that version.. any other suggestions?

Comment: Use 'disabledClass' config, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-disabledClass